# Is there someting similar with ApexCharts dashedArray for Echarts?

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

In ApexCharts there is a property inside stroke called dashedArray

```
dashArray: Number || Array of Numbers
Creates dashes in borders of svg path. Higher number creates more space between dashes in the border.
```

What this does if I have multiple series I can choose some of them to have be dashes rather than solid.

Is there something similar for Echarts couldn't find anything in docs.

This is what I want to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  lineStyle: {
          type: series.name.includes("Not") ? "dashed" : "solid",
        },
```

I found it with a simple include inside my series.map I can choose which lines will have dashes